# I have to add logging to a method in a series of controllers in SpringBoot Is there a way to do the logging without adding to the method

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I have a series of micro services that hav controllers each controller has a method

```
  @SneakyThrows
  @PostMapping(value = "/getData", produces = { "application/json" })
  public GetDataResponse getData(@RequestBody GetDataRequest data) {

  }
```

I can add logging to each controller to get the same data as each controller is called.

```
  @SneakyThrows
  @PostMapping(value = "application/<controllerApplicationName>/getData", produces = { "application/json" })
  public GetDataResponse getData(@RequestBody GetDataRequest data) {
      log.info("From client "+data.getClientId()

  }
```

Is there a way to get springboot to handle this logging, so I dont need to add logging to each controller and new controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there a way to do that, you can add **Spring AOP** to your project,
AOP is a proxy mechanism which will intercept calls to methods in your spring managed classes. But it works on public methods only.

With this you don't need to write logging code in every method, for your whole application, a single class can work.

Here's a sample code to kickstart. (And do refer online for its tutorials)

```
package com.demo.survey.aop;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.demo.controllers.*.*(..))")
    private void forControllerPackage() {}
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.demo.serviceImpl.*.*(..))")
    private void forServiceImplPackage() {}
    
    @Pointcut("forControllerPackage() || forServiceImplPackage()")
    private void applyPointCut() {}
    
    // Will get called before your method gets executed
    @Before("execution(* com.demo.controllers.demoController.addData(..)))")
    public void beforeAddQuestion(JoinPoint jt) {
        MethodSignature methodSig = (MethodSignature) jt.getSignature();
        System.out.println("methodSig = "+methodSig);
        
        Object[] args = jt.getArgs();
        for(Object tempArgs : args) {
            System.out.println("tempArgs = "+tempArgs);
        }
        
    }
    
    // @Around:- This will get called before and after your method runs.
    @Around("applyPointCut()")
    public Object logExceptions(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        //display Method Signature
        MethodSignature methodSig = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
        try {
            // execute the method
            // do something before proceeding
            
            System.out.println("methodSig = "+methodSig);
        
            Object[] args = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
            for(Object tempArgs : args) {
                // Arguments which are being passed to method
                System.out.println("tempArgs = "+tempArgs);
            }
            
            result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    } 
}


// Here are the 2 dependencies that you will need

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of AOP, but I read that it had falllen out of favour due to the fact that frameworks have taken over a lot of the cross cutting concerns. Also forgot to mention these controllers are in different microservices

Comment: @Tony then read about spring cloud and eureka server, it might help